# Rails 6 Action Mailbox internal route not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Having issues with Rails 6 Action Mailbox. I went through all the steps on the install and it appeared I had no issues with the setup. But when I navigate to localhost:3000/rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails I get the following error:

undefined method `new_rails_conductor_inbound_email_path' for #

Answer (score 6):

Setting `config.api_only = false` in `application.rb` fixed issue for me.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me also.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else following the ActionMailbox setup guide (I encountered the same issue). From what I can see, as of today (Tues Jan 7th 2020), Conductor has not yet made it into a Rails release. There is an active pull request with recent review activity, so I would guess the documentation is just a little ahead of the code.

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/35489